Are 8086 family microprocessors accumulator based?
I know that  8086 microprocessor family microprocessors are both register and stack based microprocessors.I have been searching if they were also accumulator based microprocessors but   couldnt find any reference to that so I guess they dont support accumulator type processing of data right?

In a sense, yes, the 8086 did have some (arguably legacy) accumulator instructions. But in another sense, no.
Let me explain what I mean.
There are some 8086 instructions that go through the accumulator register specifically, including:

The binary-coded decimal instructions AAA, DAA, AAS, DAS, AAM, AAD and the look-up table instruction XLAT. These are all considered deprecated.
The sign extension instructions CBW and CWD. Also considered deprecated, these have been effectively replaced by extension-on-move instructions MOVSX and MOVZX.
Port I/O instructions IN and OUT.

There are also instructions like multiplication and division, MUL, IMUL, DIV, IDIV. These are accumulator instructions, but the the DX register is also used for double word arithmetic.
String instructions (e.g. MOVSB, CMPSB) used the accumulator register, but also the source and destination registers SI and DI.
Other instructions use other registers for special purposes. For example, computed left and right shifts used the CL register for the shift amount. Similar with the looping instructions LOOP and REP, which used CX as the counter. Also note the special jump instruction JCXZ, which meant "jump if CX is zero".
So while you could say that the 8086 had some accumulator instructions, it might be more fair to say that the 8086 used certain dedicated registers for certain classes of instruction, and the accumulator register was not special in that sense.
I think of the 8086 as a step on the road from accumulator-based ISAs to the full register-transfer ISAs that we have in most general-purpose ISAs today.

Were there also some instructions with a special, shorter encoding when using AX? (Which also probably had something to do with intentional similarities with older systems, if it was even a thing.)

@ilkkachu yes, in particular loads and stores to and from AL/AX/EAX/RAX have dedicated opcodes (0xA0–0xA3), so they can be encoded using one less byte than the generic load/store to/from register instructions. MOV AX, [1234] in 16-bit mode can be encoded as A1D204 instead of the generic 8B06D204.

Deprecated? On the 8086?

@user3840170 Modern Intel-esque CPUs are 100% backwards compatible with the 8086. However, some 8086 instructions are deprecated in the sense that modern programmers are cautioned not to use them in new code, because they are less efficient than the alternative. xlat, for example, means mov al,ds:[bx+al]. A short code sequence to implement this operation will be faster on a modern CPU than xlat.

@ilkkachu: Yes, load/store of accumulator to absolute address has a shorter encoding (no ModR/M byte), and so do instructions with an immediate operand.  Like add al, 123 or add ax, 1234 are a byte shorter than with cl or cx.  On of my answers on Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code discusses the various short-form encodings and why they exist  (including 1-byte xchg ax, reg from which we get 0x90 NOP), with an 8086 design goal being easy (mechanical) porting from 8080 asm source code, which is an 8-bit accumulator ISA.

@user3840170: cbw / cdqe etc. aren't deprecated now, and were the only good option for sign-extension on 8086.  These days, cwde is still a peephole optimization that saves code size vs. movsx eax, ax if it's convenient to use those regs w/o extra movs.  And cdq (the 32-bit operand-size version of cwd) is not at all deprecated.  There's no other single-uop way to sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX as setup for idiv, unless you have 31 in a register for BMI2 sarx edx, eax, edi, or with the upcoming APX extension for 3-operand forms of legacy integer insns for sar edx, eax, 31.
